# Speed of indexedDB vs blocking memory

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-applications, indexeddb

Im working on a little webapp using indexedDB to store data I load from a server. Keeping mobile devices with less memory in mind, I was wondering how fast it is to load Data from indexedDB compared to the speed of keeping the data in the memory for runtime. Is there a speed test or a reference value of how much data should be kept in memory and when it is better to store and reload it, when needed?